# Moving into ancient apartment, two-prong outlets

Tags: electrical, grounding, surge-suppression

I just signed a lease on an apartment.  I didn't look carefully at all the outlets, but I noticed that each bedroom has exactly one outlet, and the overhead light fixture in the kitchen works by pulling a chain, i.e. there is no light switch in the wall.  So I think the electrical wiring must be very old-fashioned.

My question (I hope I may ask this here even though I do not want to do any DIY electrical work -- not sure where else to ask): may I safely plug in my laptop?  I suspect it would not be good to use a surge protector.  Should I make sure to unplug it if there's a chance of a thunderstorm?  Should I go to the library every day to charge it?

The electric company required an electrical inspection before I could open an account for the address.  The apartment passed the inspection.  I didn't have the opportunity to speak with the inspector.

Sorry, I forgot to say, I'm in the U.S., specifically New York State.

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - sorry, forgot to include location.  NY State.

Comment: Upstate or NYC?

Comment: Does your laptop charger have a "square-within-a-square" logo on it?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - Yes.  Two concentric squares, to the right of the phrases "Energy Verified" and "Rendement Energétique Vérifié."  But note this is a replacement power adapter (charger).

Comment: You shouldn't have any problems using your laptop charger with a 3 prong to 2 prong adapter with your receptacles. If there are any problems on the line the external charger will protect the laptop from damage although the charger may be sacrificed. Ditto for your cell phone charger.

Comment: I would use the 3 to 2 prong adapter but get a surge power strip to at least protect your laptop from any surges since the outlet isn't grounded.

Comment: @EricF - Thank you and thanks noybman but I thought I read that surge protectors should only be used with a grounded outlet, i.e. with a three-prong outlet.

Comment: @noybman telling people not to overload power strips is futile, unless you can teach them how to understand what that means.  Otherwise you're down to "my account can't be overdrawn! i still have 9 checks left in my checkbook!"

Comment: Don't use a 3-to-2 cheater on anything but a single device which you have vetted to assure it is double insulated.  That is, don't use power strips *at all*, as they are all 3-prong.  If you need to split a 2-prong outlet into many, every 2-prong extension cord I've ever seen has a triple tap on its far end, done.  I am also bothered by the need *for you* to inspect the electrical, that's the landlord's job unless this is not a normal-proper rental unit.  Also why not just install GFCI/AFCI dual mode breakers, this will allow you to convert the outlets to 3-prong and increase safety.

Comment: @harper Not everyone will discard the idea of "not overloading" but case in point, it is still fairly easy for a load/return imbalance especially if something else completes a ground inadvertently, so point taken. The idea of saying use a power strip was simply to get the MOV protection, which is better than nothing.

Comment: @Harper - The flat was inspected.  The electric company required that in order to create my account, because the flat was unoccupied for two years. // I must say I appreciate everyone's input here but am going to have to place a bounty, I think, because the discussion keeps getting me more and more confused.

Answer (score 7):

First yes you can connect a laptop into a two prong outlet. Is it Safe? That's anybody's guess.

My easiest answer without out rewiring the apartment is to purchase a small UPS system for your laptop. KVA size depends on your computer equipment demands. It has no direct electrical connection to the supply side power. In other words it creates it's own power. This keeps you power supply clean and constant and it protects from surges and sages and requires no electrical knowledge.

If you would like to provide a little more protection. You could ground the source side power and bond the case (should be already done within the unit).

Good Luck

Comment: The ups will provide good surge , brownout and lightning protection. Make sure if you get one to use with digital equipment to get one that creates "pure sine wave" some create a square wave that doesent work well with electronic or switching power supplies.

Comment: @EdBeal and Retired, I never heard of "UPS system."  Can you give me a sample link so I can get an idea what it costs and how to choose one that creates "pure sine wave"?

Comment: Uninterruptible power supply. You plug it in it has a battery and electronics that create 120v for a true isolated unit the output is always running from the battery/charging voltage so when there is any power disturbance your electronics never know something went wrong. Many inexpensive units will run for 15 minutes to an hour with a total power outage, more expensive larger unites are sized to the load an can run for days until the battery(s) are depleted.

Comment: Overall a good idea, however, not all UPS's are isolated you need to make sure it is a double conversion or better to be line isolated, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply

Comment: Here is a (link)[://www.tripplite.com/products] to a brand I have used in the past. Not sure why the link is not working Tryed editing brackets still looks funny on my phone maybe chasing loose horses this morning scrambled my mind.

Comment: Most laptop chargers I have seen are 2-prong.   It goes without saying that it is safe to plug a 2-prong device into a 2-prong outlet. You are confusing UPS and isolation transformer. UPS's do nothing to isolate, and in fact require a ground.  Isolation transformers don't help you when the power goes out.

Comment: Harper the ups that run off the charge/ battery are 100% isolated I have used them there are all kinds that's why I mentioned running off the charge/battery voltage and pure sine models an isolation transformer has no backup capability and would not protect from surges or brownouts because they pass the voltage they only isolate a direct neutral connection handy if using a line powered oscope when making line measurements so if the probe is connected to the line it won't cause a direct short and blow the probe and possibly the scope input.

Comment: I'm sure there exist combo isolator+UPS devices.  However that is not the advice I am seeing above, and no warning is being given to make sure the UPS is also an isolation transformer.

Comment: on the grounding topic, I would have thought it was required by current code. Perhaps the ancient apt is grandfathered? Done correctly, someone could always wire a two prong connector to rebar or pipes with jumpers in them (correct?)

Comment: @noybman -- what they really need is GFCI protection -- the problem is really more bonding than grounding (the North American terminology is unfortunate, but its been etched into code)

Comment: @EdBeal - thanks but your link is taking me to the root of the catalog, not to a particular product.  (I just need to see an example of the type of product you're recommending.)